# egrep and grep difference with dollar

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm having touble understanding the different behaviors of grep end egrep when using \$ in a pattern.

To be more specific:

```
grep "\$this->db" file   # works

egrep "\$this->db" file  # does not work

egrep "\\$this->db" file # works
```

Can some one tell me why or link some explanation?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash is being eaten by the shell's escape processing, so in the first two cases the regexp is just `$this->db`. The difference is that `grep` treats a `$` that isn't at the end of the regexp as an ordinary character, but `egrep` treats it as a regular expression that matches the end of the line.

In the last case, the double backslash causes the backslash to be sent to `egrep`. This escapes the `$`, so it gets treated as an ordinary character rather than matching the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

See `man grep`:

```
-E, --extended-regexp
              Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)
```

If regex are activated (through the usage of `egrep`) metacharacters like the backslash have to be escaped with a backslash. Therefore the need of `\\` to match a literal backslash.