# Filter lines with special symbols using grep -E?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, grep

**file.txt:**

```
vwive
wbvo$nivw
nowev^VWen
wev$
qnwe^
```

**Filter lines that constains '^' in it using command** :

```
1. grep -E "\^" file.txt
```

**Output** :

```
nowev^VWen
qnwe^
```

**Filter lines that constains '$' in it using command** :

```
2. grep -E "\$" file.txt
```

**Output** :

```
vwive
wbvo$nivw
nowev^VWen
wev$
qnwe^
```

**Command 1** gives correct output by removing the special meaning of '^' but not **command 2**.

> **Why the behaviour of both command are different**?

Comment: Try single quotes, `grep -E '\$' file.txt`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/OYolEe).

Comment: `grep -E "\\$"` or `grep -E '\$'`

Comment: Yeah, Single quotes work, but how double quotes worked in command 1 and not in command 2?

Comment: The `"\$"` is equal to `'$'`. `[[ '$' == "\$" ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no";` shows `yes`.

Comment: shell expands variable names inside double-quoted strings where `$` is a special symbol which is used in variable names  but `^` isn't

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. Why single backslash '\' doesn't remove special meaning of '$'  and we have to use backslash 2 times to search for '$' in double quotes?

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147498/egrep-and-grep-difference-with-dollar and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081624/whats-the-differences-between-grep-and-grep

Answer (score 0):

> Why the behaviour of both command are different?

Because the `\` character is an escape character inside `"` quotes, and `\$` is one of escape sequences. Some parts from [bash manual double qoutes](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes):

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!‘. [...]
> The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘"’, ‘\’, or newline.
> Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these characters are removed.
> Backslashes preceding characters without a special meaning are left unmodified.

The "special meaning" of `\` character is meant to be the escaping thing:

> A non-quoted backslash ‘\’ is the Bash escape character. It preserves the literal value of the next character that follows

Because `^` is not one of `$` `` ` `` `"` `\`, then `"\^"` preserves both `\` and `^` so it's is equal to `'\^'`.

Because `$` is one of them, then `"\$"` is equal to `'$'`. The slash get's removed and `\$` is interpreted as `$`.

Such typos are easy to find out with `set -x`.

```
$ ( set -x; grep -E "\$" /dev/null; )
+ grep -E '$' /dev/null
$ ( set -x; grep -E '\$' /dev/null; )
+ grep -E '\$' /dev/null
```

Comment: what if I want to use variable in regex like searching lines with 2 dot characters, would this work ? 
dot="."
grep -E "\.\$dot" file.txt

Comment: No it will not. Please take your time to learn about quoting. I would `grep -E '\.\'"$dot"` or `grep -E "\\.\\$dot"`

Comment: grep -E 
    "\.\\$dot" 
also works ?

Comment: Yes, because `\.` is preserved

Comment: But If variable expansion happens first than don't you think expression "\.\$dot" should get convert to "\.\." first and then regex matching?

Comment: I do not understand. `"\$dot"` does not trigger expansion, because `\$` disables the special meaning of `$`. The expansion does not "happen first" then. Or maybe, the expansion happen only if there is a `$` has "special meaning" (ie. it triggers the expansion). Within double quotes and when preceded by "\", then `$` looses it's special meaning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219406/discussion-between-tusharrawat-and-kamilcuk).